# Bash redirections. Stdout to shell and stdout+stderr to file

Tags: bash, shell, redirect, tee

In bash
is it possible to have a stdout in my shell and stdout+stderr (output of `set -x`, actually) into a file?
I tried different combinations of pipes, redirections and tee, something like:
  `command 2» output.txt | tee -a output.txt`
but couldn't manage to make it work.

Comment: I just tried it with a script (#!/bin/bash -x   NEWLINE    echo "output") and your command works.  I called it like this:  `./t.bash 2>>output.txt | tee -a output.txt`.  output.txt gets both stdout and stderr.  On my terminal I get the "output" echo.  What does it do for you?  Cause it seems to be working (Tried both RHEL7 and Mint Linux).

Comment: Make sure you use `>>` (two times the `>` character) and not the HTML entity `&raquo;` or `&#187;`.

Answer (score 0):

```
command > stdout 2> err; cat stdout err > std; cat stdout; rm stdout err
```

1. store stdout in a temporary file
2. store stderr in a temporary file
3. print both of them and store the output in a new file
4. print the new file
5. remove the temporary files